# OLS and 2SLS normal equations

Tags: econometrics, self-study

For a system of equations with $M=2$ endogenous variables, $ Y=\begin{bmatrix}  y_1 & y_2 \end{bmatrix}$ and $K=3$ exogenous variables, $X=\begin{bmatrix}  x_1 & x_2 & x_3 \end{bmatrix}$. 
The first equation of the system is given by: 
$y_{1i}=\gamma_{12}y_{2i}+\beta_{11}x_{1i}+\epsilon_{1i}$.
The data matrices yield, $X'X$, $X'Y$ and $Y'Y$, which are of dimension, $3*3$, $3*2$ and $2*2$ respectively

I need to

- Write the OLS and 2SLS normal equations in terms of cross products of the data matrices.

I tried using the standard procedure for deriving normal equations, that is, by minimizing sum of squared residuals, but I fail to understand how the equations can be modelled in form of the cross products of the given data matrices. I think I'm missing the point of the exercise. Please help me in understanding what the question demands. Thanks!

Comment: Note that $x_1, x_2, x_3, y_1$ and $y_2$ are all $n\times 1$ vectors.

Answer (score 1):

**OLS**

The OLS part is clear: $\sum_{i=1}^n y_{2i} (y_{1i} - \hat\gamma_{12} y_{2i} - \hat\beta_{11} x_{1i}) = 0$ and $\sum_{i=1}^n x_{1i} (y_{1i} - \hat\gamma_{12} y_{2i} - \hat\beta_{11} x_{1i}) = 0$, where $\hat\gamma_{12}$ and $\hat\beta_{11}$ are the OLS estimators.

**2SLS**

For 2SLS, I will assume that $(x_{1i}, x_{2i}, x_{3i})$ is used as IV. The corresponding 2SLS is identical to the IV estimator using $\hat{y}_{2i}$ and $x_{1i}$ as IV. Thus, (I think) the "normal equations" are
\begin{align}
\sum_{i=1}^n \hat{y}_{2i} (y_{1i} - \tilde\gamma_{12} y_{2i} - \tilde\beta_{11} x_{1i}) &= 0,\\
\sum_{i=1}^n x_{1i} (y_{1i} - \tilde\gamma_{12} y_{2i} - \tilde\beta_{11} x_{1i}) &= 0,
\end{align}
where $\tilde\gamma_{12}$ and $\tilde\beta_{11}$ are the 2SLS estimators using $x_{1i}, x_{2i}, x_{3i}$ as IV, and $\hat{y}_{2i}$ is the fitted value obtained by regressing $y_{2i}$ on the instruments $x_{1i}$, $x_{2i}$ and $x_{3i}$.

In the above, I understood 2SLS as the IV estimator using $(\hat{y}_{2i}, x_{1i})$ as IV. We can also understand 2SLS as the OLS estimator of $y_{1i}$ on $(\hat{y}_{2i}, x_{1i})$. In that case, the normal equations can be written as
\begin{align}
\sum_{i=1}^n \hat{y}_{2i} (y_{1i} - \tilde\gamma_{12} \hat{y}_{2i} - \tilde\beta_{11} x_{1i}) &= 0,\\
\sum_{i=1}^n x_{1i} (y_{1i} - \tilde\gamma_{12} \hat{y}_{2i} - \tilde\beta_{11} x_{1i}) &= 0,
\end{align}
where $y_{2i}$ is replaced with $\hat{y}_{2i}$. The two sets of normal equations for 2SLS (one in terms of $y_{2i}$ and the other in terms of $\hat{y}_{2i}$) are identical.

**Intercept**

I have noticed that the intercept is excluded in the question. If the model is $y_{1i} = \beta_{10} + \gamma_{12} y_{2i} + \beta_{11} x_{1i} + \epsilon_i$ instead, you need equations for the intercept as well.

**Matrix notations**

Using matrix notations, let $y$ be the $n\times 1$ matrix of the LHS variable, $X$ the $n\times 2$ matrix of $(y_{2i}, x_{1i})$ and $Z$ the $n\times 3$ matrix of $(x_{i1}, x_{i2}, x_{i3})$. Let $\beta = (\gamma_{12}, \beta_{11})'$. (I am considering the model without the intercept. For the model with the intercept, $X$ and $Z$ contain a column of ones.) Then the OLS estimator is $\hat\beta = (X'X)^{-1} X'y$, which solves the normal equations $X'(y-X\hat\beta)=\boldsymbol 0$. To see this, note that $$X'(y-X\hat\beta)=\boldsymbol 0 \\
X'y - X'X\hat\beta = \boldsymbol 0\\
X'X\hat\beta = X'y\\
\hat\beta = (X'X)^{-1}X'y$$

The 2SLS (using $Z$ as instruments) estimator is $$\tilde\beta = [X'Z(Z'Z)^{-1} Z'X]^{-1} X'Z(Z'Z)^{-1} Z'y = (\hat{X}'X)^{-1} \hat{X}'y$$ where $\hat{X} = Z(Z'Z)^{-1} Z'X$. This 2SLS solves $\hat{X}' (y-X\tilde\beta)=\boldsymbol 0$, the normal equations for this 2SLS. Again, to see this, note that 
$$\hat{X}' (y-X\tilde\beta)=\boldsymbol 0\\
\hat X'y - \hat X'X\tilde\beta = \boldsymbol 0\\
\hat X'X\tilde\beta = \hat X' y\\
\tilde\beta = (\hat X'X)^{-1} \hat X'y $$
You will see that $\hat{X}$ is the $n\times 2$ matrix of $(\hat{y}_{2i}, x_{1i})$. It is also true that $\tilde\beta = (\hat{X}'\hat{X})^{-1} \hat{X}'y$, and the normal equations are also written as $\hat{X}' (y-\hat{X}\tilde\beta)=0$. The two different expressions are identical because $\hat{X}'X = \hat{X}'\hat{X}$.

Comment: Note that $\boldsymbol {X'}(\boldsymbol y-\boldsymbol{X\hat\beta})=\boldsymbol 0$ is a $K\times 1$ vector. This corresponds to the equations at the beginning of the answer.

Comment: I've just found that my $X$ is different from OP's $X$. Sorry.

Comment: Note that $(Z'Z)^{-1}Z'X$ is a matrix of coefficients, so $\hat X = Z(Z'Z)^{-1}Z'X$ is a $N\times 2$ matrix of the predicted values of the regressions of $\boldsymbol {y_2}$ and $\boldsymbol {x_1}$ on $\boldsymbol {x_1}, \boldsymbol {x_2}$ and $\boldsymbol {x_3}$ (known as the "projection"). You can see that $\boldsymbol{\hat x_1} = \boldsymbol {x_1}$ since $\boldsymbol {x_1}, \boldsymbol {x_2}$ and $\boldsymbol {x_3}$ are independent. However, $\boldsymbol {\hat y_2}\neq\boldsymbol {y_2}$.

Comment: no, I didn't pick up any mistakes in your answer.

Comment: You re-defined $X$, which was the correct thing to do (in order to maintain conventional notation).

Comment: Yes, I did. I noticed it after reading your first comment. Hope your comment helps people.